# Jquery get element by id, multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the value of a specific html input that is named like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="." id="grid[0][0]">
```

where [0][0] could be any value within a foreach loop.

using Jquery:

```
var currVal = $('#grid['+x+']['+y+']').html();
```

I'm getting an undefined value. Not sure whether it's a syntax problem. I haven't found a similar example so I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: I...don't have a solution to this specific problem. I will *only* say that in 99% of cases, if you have an `id` with a number in it, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is a syntax problem. jQuery interprets "#grid[...]" as an HTML element with the ID "grid" and some attribute (or other meta stuff) **just like CSS would**.

To solve simply escape the `[` and `]`, like this:

```
$('#grid\\[' + x + '\\]\\[' + y + '\\]').val()
```

That should do it :)

Edit: As noted by Josh Crozier, the `html()` method is supposed to be used in normal tags (like div). For `input`, `select` or `textarea` you should use `val()` -- Docs on that: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Yep, that would work. But it's also worth pointing out that [bracket characters are invalid in an ID attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)... also, the OP is using the `.html()` method... it should be `.val()` since an `input` element can't contain HTML..

Comment: Yeah, good you remembered that! Thanks! Totally forgot about the html()/val() thing (been ages since I used jQuery myself). Weird thing is that those IDs do work (albeit not recommended)

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not know about the brackets either, will remove that from the html ID :D

Comment: @JoshCrozier no more with HTML5 the id could contain special characters...https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
var currVal = $('input[id="grid['+x+']['+y+']"]').val();
```